# How to convert Google Cloud Storage base64 md5sum to hexadecimal version?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

Google cloud storage represents the [md5hash](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects) of objects using base64 encoded values.

How can I convert those values to the hexadecimal versions reported by md5sum?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`binascii.hexlify`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify) (or [`binascii.b2a_hex`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.b2a_hex)):

```
import base64
import binascii

print binascii.hexlify(base64.urlsafe_b64decode(md5_base64))
```

Comment: I think there's a typo in the import; I think you meant 'import base64'. SO won't let me edit it since its lets than 6 characters. I like your answer better since it doesn't require numpy.

Comment: @JeremyLewi, You're right. I updated answer accordingly. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

## `md5sum` compatible hash listings from GCS

For anyone else looking for a native command line / coreutils way of check your Cloud store integrity - for example, you're just visiting Storage through browser, or the files you're trying to verify are stored elsewhere, and you just wanted to generate a `.md5` hash listing to run `md5sum -c` later.

For any GCS bucket directory listing with `gsutil ls -L`, piping the output through this block (either through an `alias` or a bash script)

```
awk 'BEGIN { \
    decodehash = "base64 -d | xxd -p | tr -d \"\\n\""; \
    truncname = "sed \"s/gs:\/\/[a-z0-9_.\-]*\///\" | sed \"s/:$//\"" } \
    /Hash \(md5\)/ { print $3 | decodehash; close(decodehash); \
        printf "  %s\n",fname | truncname; close(truncname) } \
    /^gs:\/\// { fname = $0 }'
```

should generate an output that is compatible with verification using `md5sum -c` locally. Basically it's an `awk` block that looks for `gs://` lines and `Hash (md5):` lines, swap their order (so that the hash gets printed before the filename), and use `base64 -d` and `xxd` to convert the hash to hex string.

### Example

```
analogist@project-1111$ ls -L gs://bucket-name/directory
gs://bucket-name/directory/file1.tar.gz
        Creation time: Wed, 10 Aug 2016 23:17:06 GMT
        [...]
        Hash (crc32c):          a4X4cQ==
        Hash (md5):             2xXYMp7aacmOZ+M57KHEbA==
        [..]
gs://bucket-name/directory/file2.tar.gz
        Creation time: Wed, 10 Aug 2016 23:26:16 GMT
        [...]
        Hash (crc32c):          JVo9EA==
        Hash (md5):             XdrBIyCaADR9arH67ucdEA==
        [..]
```

I can save the above awk code block to the file `md5convert`, and:

```
analogist@project-1111$ ls -L gs://bucket-name/directory | bash md5convert
db15d8329eda69c98e67e339eca1c46c  directory/file1.tar.gz
5ddac123209a00347d6ab1faeee71d10  directory/file2.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simply python recipe using numpy.

```
import numpy as np
b=np.frombuffer(base64.urlsafe_b64decode(md5_base64), dtype=np.uint8)
print "".join(["%0x"%  l for l in b])
```

Here md5_base64 is the value reported by Google Cloud Storage. You can get that value by running the ocmmand

```
gsutil stat gs://PATH/TO/FILE
```

The output should include Hash (md5) (assuming its a [non composite object](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hashes-etags#_JSONAPI)).